# Fedora 27: how to limit xserver restart attempts?

Tags: fedora, gnome

I am running Fedora 27 (problem also relates to Fedora 25) and it is very often that when I upgrade my kernel (via a "dnf update") the NVIDIA graphics driver will not work anymore. After reboot (target is level 5) the system gets stuck in a perpetual loop of trying to restart a failed xserver.

More details:

Typically, the upgrade of system and kernel will be successful, I will then reboot and the system will boot OK up until the point where it says "**starting GNOME**" where it will try to spawn the xserver, it will fail (because of NVIDIA driver most likely needs upgrading or plain re-compiling too) and *stupidly* attempt to restart the xserver for about a million times with milliseconds in between.

At this time the system becomes unusable because of the xserver loop and I am also afraid the monitor may blow up too. DoS via Stupidity? Or electronic headbanging?

I can see the command line login prompt but I can not login (so as to kill the re-start attempts or set init to 3) because the system is in a constant loop and it misses keystrokes from the keyboard when I type my password etc. The options at that stage is either to login remotely or to reboot with older kernel, then download latest NVIDIA driver, install and reboot.

QUESTION: how can I limit the million attempts to restart a failed xserver to just 1 or 2?

Please don't tell me how to init 3 and re-install NVIDIA. I know that. I want to know how to get from that loop of death if I forget to init 3 after kernel upgrades. Thanks.

(crossposted on LinuxQuestions.org and https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?318110-Fedora-27-how-to-limit-xserver-restart-attempts&s=e3a81ad1989fba1547a6fe0905433a9a a week ago with no meaningful results.)

Comment: Exactly how did you install the NVIDIA driver? If you didn't use negativo17, you should be using negativo17.

Comment: I download the ".sh" file from Nvidia's drivers page and run it. It never failed me except when I forget to do it. Do you have a suggestion about whether is a xserver respawning issue and where to find the max num respawn? thanks

Comment: I suggest you simply use negativo17 so you don't have to worry about it anymore.

Comment: It's actually a 30 second timeout on the display-manager.service where it keeps retrying until the timer ticks out. Just go get coffee and prepare to fix the issue in the meantime.